# Can purchased equipment be sold?

Tags: lethal-company

If I purchase a piece of equipment that I don't need anymore, can I sell it to recover some of the cost? For example, if I buy a flashlight and then later pick up a pro flashlight, can I sell the regular flashlight? Will it count towards the quota?

Comment: Fell short on quota once. Decided to try and sell flashlights and flash bangs, they gave us 0 credits.